# show that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ gcd($n^2 - n + 1, n +1)$ is either $1$ or $3$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, divisibility

show that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ gcd($n^2 - n + 1, n +1)$ is either $1$ or $3$.

My Work:

I considered the case where $n =-1$ , and the case $n \not= 1$.

So when $n\not= -1$  we can let $n^2 - n+ 1 = (n-2)(n + 1) + 3$.

We know that when $n=1$ it is clear that the gcd is $1$. However I am having trouble with the case when $n \not= 1$ any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ By Euclid's algorithm $\ \gcd(n\!+\!1,\,3+(n\!+\!1)k) = \gcd(n\!+\!1,3)$

Comment: therefore since gcd(n+1, 3) will never be greater than 3 we can conclude that the gcd is either 1 or 3?

Comment: Hint: $\,\gcd(n\!+\!1,3)\mid 3.\,$ What are the divisors of $\,3\,?\ \ $

Comment: the only divisors are 3 and 1

Comment: Right, which completes the proof.